# Java Applet Permission Denied when preloading 2 jars

Tags: java, permissions, jar, applet, archive

I have an error `SecurityException Permission denied: file:/d:/Notes/Notes.jar` when I'm trying to start my applet.

I need to use 2 jars in my applet:

1. Applet.jar - the jar stores the applet's code (the jar is signed and works fine)
2. Notes.jar - this is a library that allows to work with Lotus Notes
   databases.

The first jar is loaded from server, and the second should be loaded from user's laptop (local file that stored on the laptop where the applet should be run).

I'm using the html code:

```
<APPLET CODE = "com.example.AppletClass" WIDTH = 640 HEIGHT = 480
archive="Applet.jar,file:///${user.apiPath}">
<PARAM NAME = "db_path" VALUE ="${user.dbPath}">
<PARAM NAME = "view_name" VALUE ="${user.viewName}">
Your browser doesn't support applets
</APPLET>
```

the problem is in the line: **archive="Applet.jar,file:///${user.apiPath}"**

`${user.apiPath} = d:/Notes/Notes.jar`

The second jar can't be loaded. But if I move the second jar to the server and load it to client's laptop everything works fine.

Unfortunately the solution is not very good for me.

Is there any possibility to load 2 jars from different places: server and local?

Comment: *"The first jar is loaded from server, and the second should be loaded from user's laptop"* Why on earth would you not deliver the 2nd Jar from the server?

Comment: The second jar is version specific so I need to get the proper jar from user's laptop.
Lotus Notes 7's jar doesn't work with Lotus Notes 8.5
Lotus Notes 8.5's jar doesn't work with Lotus Notes 7

Comment: I think instead you should offer different applet pages for versions 7 & 8.5, and add the appropriate Jars for each.  Or better still, lose the applet completely, put the GUI in a frame & launch it using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) direct from a link.  You might add both Jars to be loaded lazily, as different download 'parts' of the application - with programmatic control of which Jar is cached for the user.  Note that I suspect your current approach will always be problematic.  JREs are designed to protect the user, and do not like split code bases.

Comment: @user592704 as I've mentioned:  
`Applet.jar - the jar stores the applet's code (**the jar is signed and works fine**)`

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed...

You writing you have path like a

> d:/Notes/Notes.jar

I am not pretty sure but local file paths (in win at least) are using backslash

> x:\folder\file.txt

Anyway, that would be more helpful you to point which OS is about.

And one more thing...

The exception says the applet is trying to get jar as

> file:/d:/*jar's_folder_path*/jar-name.jar

... but you say the applet requires the jar

> d:/Notes/Notes.jar

So I just want to ask does the Notes.jar exist on the client machine?

Comment: `I am not pretty sure but local file paths (in win at least) are using backslash......Anyway, that would be more helpful you to point which OS is about.`

I've tried different slashes on the jar path (the path will be entered by user in TextField).
I'm using Windows 7, but the code should be as much OS-independent as it can be.

`file:/d:/*jar's_folder_path*/jar-name.jar  =  d:/Notes/Notes.jar`

It was my fault. I've fixed it already.